# APDU command to read Track1/track2 data from NFC card and MobileApp

Tags: nfc, emv

Application is in C, to read only NFC card details(card number & date). Following the steps below

1. `CardRead("1PAY.SYS.DDF01", "PSE1");`
   Ex:APDU - (0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, PSE1,00) or
2. `CardRead("2PAY.SYS.DDF01", "PSE2");`
   Ex:APDU - (0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, PSE2,00)
3. Select the AID Get the AID from response data.
   Ex:APDU - (0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, AID,00)
4. ReadRecord - Want to know how to calculate SFI & P1,P2 values.

Is PDOL required or only Read Record command is enough to read track1/2 data?

After step 3 data received is `3 6F 38 84 7 A0 0 0 0 4 10 10 A5 2D 50 A 4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 87 1 1 5F 2D 2 65 6E 9F 38 9 9F 1D 8 9F 1A 2 9F 35 1 BF C A 9F 6E 7 8 40 0 0 32 31 0 90 0 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 9F 65 2 0 E0 9F 66 2 F 1E 9F 67 1 4 9F 6B 13 51 80 84 8 2 59 9 27 D2 20 92 1 0 0 0 0 0 0`.

This is PDOL information: `9F 38 9 9F 1D 8 9F 1A 2 9F 35 1`.

Please let me know how to frame next command PDOL/ReadRecord from the above data to read track1/track2 data.

Comment: yes it will come in READ RECORD. you can check my answer to understand how to process the AFL and get required information.

Answer (score 0):

Download EMV Book 3, read section 10.2 Read Application Data. It has it all. Find below in case you cant get the document.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, Pls let know how can we get AFL & SFI data ? without sending GPO command.

Comment: The AFL is received in GPO. SFI is a part of AFL. If AFL is not received in GPO, you cant do READ RECORDs

Comment: First step is PSE , then AID  after this step can we send READ RECORDS or GPO command is mandatory to sent.                                                                      If GPO is neccessary, pls provide steps to frame GPO command to get AFL data. I have tried below command, but doesnt work                                                                                                                                The command 80 A8 00 00 len 83 (len-2) 00.... if provided this command filling with zero, getting error.

Comment: SELECT PSE will get you the list of applications on the card. Then preferred applications SELECT. then GPO. In GPO if you receive AFL, do READ RECORDs. Can you update your question with original logs ?

Comment: Below are the commands send:                                                                                               
# Select PPSE
send: 00 A4 04 00 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 00
resp: 6F 3B 84 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 29 BF 0C 26 61 10 4F 07 A0 00 00 00 42 10 10 50 02 43 42 87 01 01 61 12 4F 07 A0 00 00 00 03 10 10 50 04 56 49 53 41 87 01 02 90 00                                                              And AID from the above data is successful.

Comment: # Select AID
send: 00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 00 42 10 10 00
resp: 6F 37 84 07 A0 00 00 00 42 10 10 A5 2C 9F 38 18 9F 66 04 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 BF 0C 0E DF 60 02 0B 1E DF 61 01 03 9F 4D 02 0B 1E 90 00
# Read Record
send: 00 B2 01 0C 00  - Here Error is 6700 , Pls explain on framing GPO with above log and where AFL data present. I have to read all types of NFC card track2 data.

Comment: After SELECTing the desired application, it should by followed by a GET PO. In your case you have a PDOL in SELECT response. PDOL data need to be provided in GET POS. Once GET PO is successful, you can look for AFL in GET PO response. If AFL is present, refer the document I have attached to frame the READ RECORD.

Comment: "it should by followed by a GET PO " - what is the command for this GET PO?

Comment: Get processing options. You need to read the specifications. There are no shortcuts.